# R: How to find empty dfs in a list?

Tags: r, lapply

I want to find empty data frames in my list. Here a basic example:

```
lst <- list("111.2012"=data.frame("Area"=1, "Value"=2),
            "112.2012"=data.frame("Area"=c(1:5), "Value"=c(6:10)))
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) x[-1,])
```

How can I find my empty df in `lst` using `lapply` as I have more than 1500 dfs in the list? I need the element-names that are similar to the ones in the example. Thanks

**Edit:** Sorry, maybe I was not explicit enough in my explenation,

1. as they were some lack of understanding, as I didn't know how to create a reproducible example with an empty df with same colnames. I create a one line df and a 5 line df and later get rid of first line --> this gives a list of one empty df and a 4 row df.
2. I need the `names` of the empty dfs, I don't want to remove them as I need them.

Comment: You probably should include an empty df in your example...

Comment: that's why I delete the first row, as I didn't know how to do it otherwise

Comment: Updated the solution though I didn't understand your description `but I have to feel at least one value in those`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to remove the empty dfs in the `list`

```
Filter(nrow, lst)
```

Or to get a logical vector of empty dfs

```
i1 <- sapply(lst, nrow)!=0
lst[i1]
```

#### Update

If we need the names of the dataframes that is empty

```
names(i1)[!i1]
#[1] "111.2012"
```